# salesforce latest dumps for dev 401 exam

Tags: certification

I am going to take exam in just a couple of weeks ( 16 july 2014 ). As I have read the study material so now I need the LATEST dumps for this exam. I read from somewhere that many of the dumps available online are outdated. So I would appreciate if anyone can help me refer the latest dumps . Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read documentation not dumps

Comment: You also never know if what you're looking at is accurate. Some of those things can destroy your confidence and cause you to make mistakes. I suggest you use the following search engine to see what you can find: http://findsf.info/

Comment: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/28467/dev-401-exam-preparation

Answer (score 8):

I would like to extend on @Bachovski's comment: "Read documentation, not dumps".

**Focussing to much on dumps of real or similar exam questions won't improve your knowledge much , or truly assess if you have reached a certain level of salesforce knowledge and experience.** You might pass the exam, be certified, but still not really know the things you ought to be knowing.

If you want to value the certification level you hope to reach, consider that it's relevant that it truly does express a level of knowledge and experience that is more than studying example questions, high level knowledge and passing an exam.  Additionally, **if you do not prepare in this manner for exams, you can use them to assess your own progress and reflect on the evolution of your knowledge.**

Personally I haven't prepared  for half of the certification exams that I've done, still passing them has shown me that I truly have the knowledge that I wanted to have.

**How to:**
A much better approach than dumps, to practise or prepare yourself is:

- Take the courses listed in the study guide
- Do read the documentation, take your time doing so.
- Read implementation guides, and do the implementation in a developer org. If needed repeatedly, first with the guide, a second time without the guide.

The Certified Developer exam is based around knowing how to configure applications and basic automation in salesforce, testing if you know salesforce and it's features and knowing when code based development is required. It is the easiest certification, so don't stress out too much. Take it and see how it goes. If you fail, don't feel bad. Try to remember which questions were challenging, and work on those areas.

Comment: Many thanks for your valuable reply Samuel . I really appreciate the way you have suggested and will follow your guide lines for sure. :-)